# SignalR doesn't work in client side in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm using SignalR libs for my c# project and I can't understand why it isn't working. I have these in my server side

[image]

and in client side

[image]

but I'm having an error, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'systemHealthHub' of undefined`. 
What did I miss ? I haven't got such a file `<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>` file in my project. Maybe was that the reason?  Can someone help me pls? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Double check your Start.cs

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        app.MapSignalR();

    }
```

Then change this line.

```
var healthInfo = $.connection.systemHealth;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not bringing in the `/signalr/hubs` file.

Bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/signalr").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-{version}.js"));
```

View:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/signalr")
    @Scripts.Render("/signalr/hubs")
}
```